# DOM not updating after POST

Tags: angularjs, django, ngresource

Using https://github.com/blacklocus/angular-django-rest-resource in my Django+angular app and my `ng-repeat` updates correctly when issuing a 'DELETE' request, but doesn't with 'POST'

relevant controller code:

```
var Project = djResource('api/projects/:id', {'id': "@id"});
$scope.projects = Project.query();
$scope.newProject = new Project;
$scope.createProject = function(){
  apiSrv.request('POST', 'projects/', $scope.newProject,
   function(data){
    $scope.projects = Project.query();
   },
   function(err){
    $log.error(err);
   }
  );
};
$scope.deleteProject = function(id){
  apiSrv.request('DELETE', 'projects/'+id, {},
   function(data){
    $scope.projects = Project.query();
   },
   function(err){
    $log.error(err);
   }
  );
};
```

relevant service code:

```
.factory('apiSrv', ['$http', function($http){
  var apiSrv = {};

  apiSrv.request = function(method, url, args, successFn, errorFn){
    return $http({
      method: method,
      url: '/api/' + url,
      data: JSON.stringify(args)
    }).success(successFn).error(errorFn);
  };

  return apiSrv;
}]);
```

I've tried calling `$scope.$apply();` during the POST callback. Also tried `$scope.projects.push(project);`.

I've also tried

```
$scope.newProject.$save(function(data){
  $scope.projects = Project.query();
});
```

along with `$scope.projects.push(project);` and `$scope.$apply();` in the $save callback and nothing I've tried updates the DOM. It works fine in the `deleteProject` function, the DOM updates to show the updated state of $scope.projects. Adding `$log.info($scope.projects);` lists any newly added projects, but again, the DOM stays the same regardless of what I do.  Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: If your question is about the DOM then it's not the worst idea to post the relevant HTML.

Comment: @zeroflagL The relevant HTML is simply `<md-list-item ng-repeat="project in projects" class="project md-no-proxy ng-scope" role="listitem">`

Comment: Side note, why did you stop using promises and instead decided to use successFn/errorFn callbacks?

Comment: @MathewBerg uhh, I dont know. Is there a vast difference between the two?

Comment: Generally you stick with one and try not to mix them. I personally like promises better as it's fewer things passed around. It was just an observation :)

Comment: `query` is asynchronous. There could be an assignment to `$scope.projects` between `Project.query()` and receiving the response. That would make `query` useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved this. I'm using Angular Material, and my project form was inside a material dialog which apparently creates an isolate scope. I needed to assign the current scope as a property of the dialog then reference the model via that property.

e.g.

```
$mdDialog.show({
    controller: function(){this.parent = $scope;},
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    ...
```

and in my view use `ng-model: "ctrl.parent.newProject.project_name"` and so on.